# Добавил библиотеку как модуль, она в другом package. Как ею воспользоваться?

Tags: android, android-studio

Добавил библиотеку как модуль и вот package у неё такой каким установил автор библиотеки. Пытаюсь импортировать класс библиотеки, но, так как она в другом package , ее не видно. Мне активити в пакете библиотеки создавать что ли.. что то я не врубаюсь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модуль должен быть прописан в `dependencies` у другого модуля, чтобы использовать его — как и обычную библиотеку:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':yourModuleName')
}
```

Если вы добавляли его через `Import Module` или создавали, автоматически он в зависимости не пропишется.